# "Too many arguments" when trying to change directory

Tags: bash, command-line, cd

I am relatively new in command line. i installed the hyoer terminal and changing directory in cd was working just fine. today whenever i try to change directory using cd it give me the bash: cd: too many arguments. I cannot move lower than the default directory that is the users.

Comment: what is result of `type cd` ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete command that you are using.

Comment: Did your folders have space between them?!

Comment: Try putting quotes around the folder name...

Answer (score 2):

There are possibly 2 ways to avoid this error of "Too many arguments" on bash terminal if your folder name has spaces in between

1. `cd "some directory"` By enclosing the folder name in quotes
2. `cd some\ directory`  By including a backslash as shown

Answer (score 0):

`cd` requires exactly 1 argument: the name of the directory that you are changing to. You supplied more than one argument.

There are multiple reasons why `cd` can get more than 1 argument. For example, I am a lazy typer, so I often use `*`, as in:

```
$ ls
drwxr-xr-x   3 ljm users    4096 Oct 25 18:58 a
drwxr-xr-x   3 ljm users    4096 Oct 25 18:58 very_long_directory_name
$ cd ver*
```

That works, until I create a directory `very_important_files`.

The most obvious however is that you have a space in your directory name. For example, if you have a directory called `directory with space`, and you do `cd directory with space`, the bash will interpret this as the command `cd`, with three arguments:

- directory
- with
- space

Which is not what you want. You can force the bash to treat it as one single argument by quoting it: `cd "directory wth space"`

Answer (score 0):

**Just make sure there is no space in the address**

- D:\Learn Git
- See there is space between Learn And Git That should not    be there

Hope I cleared your doubt !!!

Comment: How is this different from the answer a year + ago?  Is `bash` used with Windows?